# Scope and Namespace questions

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope

I was examining various JavaScript libraries for learning purposes. Basically I want to find the best way to initiliaze a namespace and see how pros load up all the associated files in their libraries. I came across this a few times in the main file (for example lets call it myNameSpace.js)  that the library user would call in a few libraries:

```
(function() {

    var jsFiles = window.MyNameSpace;

    window.MyNameSpace = {
        _getScriptLocation: (function() { 
            /* some code here */ 
        })
    };

    if(!jsFiles) { 
        jsFiles = [/* An array of ALL the library files! */];
    }

    for(var i=0, len = jsFiles.length; i<len; i++) { 
        scriptTags[i] = "<script src='" + jsFiles[i]  + "'></script>"; 
    }

    if(scriptTags.length > 0) { 
        document.write(scriptTags.join("")); 
    }

})();
```

So, with this setup, if the library user wanted to include only certain portions of the library, they would specify before loading the myNameSpace.js by doing something along the lines of:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> window.MyNameSpace = ["libraryFile1.js", "libraryFile2.js", "libraryFile3.js"]</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="MyNameSpace.js"></script>
```

My question is, window.MyNameSpace is an object and if the script assigns jsFiles to an array setup as window.MyNameSpace, this is going to be an assignment by reference, correct? But immediately after that line, window.MyNameSpace gets completely changed. So shouldn't jsFiles no longer reference the original array that was passed in? What am I missing here in my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS does not assign "by reference", assignment is copying, but when we assign objects, we copy their addresses, not objects "themselves".

Look

```
window.MyNameSpace = ["libraryFile1.js", "libraryFile2.js", "libraryFile3.js"]
```

`window.MyNameSpace` point to some object in memory. Let's assume its address is 0x12345

```
var jsFiles = window.MyNameSpace;
```

`jsFiles` now points to the same object (0x12345)

```
window.MyNameSpace = {...}
```

`window.MyNameSpace` now points to some other object (let it be 0x56789), but `jsFiles` still points to the first object (0x12345).

Comment: This is clearly what is going on. What I don't understand is, I thought a var assigned to an array would be assigned by reference.

Comment: @renosis: terminology varies from language to language, but in javascript you assign (and call) [by sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) not by reference. "By reference" means you can create variables that alias each other. php supports that, but not javascript.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I just got confused because I would try to make a copy of an array, then the array would change and it would change in the copy too. I think I see the difference here.